# Setting value between classes (via set/get methods)

Tags: java, android

I have one model class for defining variables and when I'm trying to set some value from my MainActivity to Model class, I'm getting errors.

From my MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   private ListView productList;
   private OfferModel offerModel;

        @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        productList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        ...many codes here...

        productList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                    long arg3) {

                    offerModel.setProductName(arg0.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());


            }
        });

    }}
```

And this is from my Model class

```
public class OfferModel {


    private String productName;
    public String getProductName(){return this.productName;}
    public void setProductName(String pName){ this.productName=pName;}
}
```

And here is my Log result

```
08-01 11:17:46.446: W/dalvikvm(2305): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4b70648)
08-01 11:17:46.446: E/AndroidRuntime(2305): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-01 11:17:46.446: E/AndroidRuntime(2305): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-01 11:17:46.446: E/AndroidRuntime(2305):     at stok.kontrol.noyagrup.MainActivity$2.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:71)
08-01 11:17:46.446: E/AndroidRuntime(2305):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
08-01 11:17:46.446: E/AndroidRuntime(2305):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
08-01 11:17:46.446: E/AndroidRuntime(2305):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2788)
08-01 11:17:46.446: E/AndroidRuntime(2305):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3463)
08-01 11:17:46.446: E/AndroidRuntime(2305):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
08-01 11:17:46.446: E/AndroidRuntime(2305):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-01 11:17:46.446: E/AndroidRuntime(2305):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-01 11:17:46.446: E/AndroidRuntime(2305):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-01 11:17:46.446: E/AndroidRuntime(2305):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-01 11:17:46.446: E/AndroidRuntime(2305):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-01 11:17:46.446: E/AndroidRuntime(2305):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-01 11:17:46.446: E/AndroidRuntime(2305):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-01 11:17:46.446: E/AndroidRuntime(2305):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What I'm missing ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`OfferModel offerModel` is not instantiated and is `null`. So, when you call `offerModel.setProductName(arg0.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());` you get an exception.

Comment: What? Wrong! this.productName = pName won't throw any exception. offerModel.setProductName(arg0.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()); will throw it.

Answer (score 2):

You have not initialized  `private OfferModel offerModel;` in you code and you are using  `offerModel.setProductName(arg0.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());` as it will throw `NPE`

So first initialize it moreover `productName` is `null` which is not yet initialized but you can initialize it by the use of `parameterized` `constructor` *(You have to add constructor first)*.

```
offerModel=new OfferModel(productNameValue);//Pass initial value of `productName`
//So it will first initialize your productName
```

And Add constructor

```
public OfferModel(String pro){
   productName=pro;
}
```

Or from the code I can see you love `this` keyword, so you can do it like ***this***

```
public OfferModel(String productName){
   this.productName=productName;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
         productList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {
                 offerModel= new OfferModel();
                 offerModel.setProductName(arg0.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());


        }
    });
```